# Since installing QGIS 3.10.1-A Coruña I can't get Python script to work in IDLE: ImportError: No module named qgis.core

Tags: pyqgis, importerror, idle

I have tried adding sys.path.append and under cmd.exe set Python Path but am still getting the dreaded ImportError: No module named qgis.core.

I set PythonPath to C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python

I have referenced sys.path.append material on this forum and on the QGIS site and I am still getting the error.

I am using IDLE to run scripts.

Can you provide any guidance?

Here is my Script to round raster cell values:

```
# Description: Converts each cell value of a raster to an integer by proper rounding
# Import required modules
# Python modules

import sys
sys.path.append("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python")
sys.path.append("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages")
sys.path.append("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis")

import time
import os
# Qgis modules
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo, QSettings

import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([
"gdal_translate", "-of", "GTiff", "-ot", "Int32", 
"H:/test/demtest1.tif", "H:/test/output/int.tif"
])

#done
print("done")
```

Comment: If you try `print("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python")`, you will see that you've forgotten to either escape the backslash characters (by doubling them) or use unix-style right slashes. However, I tried fixing that and got another import error (when trying to load `qgis._core`, despite `_core.pyd` being in what seemed to me to be an appropriate location). So I can't give you a full answer.

Comment: The [accepted answer to another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22897/137234) says to also add something to your system's `PATH` (note: *not* the same thing as `system.path`). Did you try this? Also, since you have OSGeo4W installed, are you running IDLE *from* there? From what the answer I linked said, I would expect that might fix the problem, without needing to change any `path`s or `PATH`s.

Comment: Thank you. I will look. FYI, I am a novice with Python. Only a few weeks in and learning on the fly. QGIS the same. I am not sure how to run IDLE from within OSGeo4W.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have OSGeo4W installed on my machine to try it myself. I found some information about that in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/214073/137234) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25836182/3004881). What is your end goal with using the QGIS libraries? I noticed that the code example you posted did not use any of them—you could delete everything above `import subprocess`. Are you trying to write code that works without opening QGIS? Or code to run inside a running QGIS?

Comment: I’m trying to create a script to run outside of QGIS. Guess no particular reason to do so other than trying to grow my programming skills.